# SQL Duplicate column names not supported

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named loansRepaid as seen below, and I need to write a query as described below.

```
loanid      repaidday    dueday      settleday    payratio
301      2018-09-23    2019-02-10      14              0.0
302      2018-02-12    2018-02-24      88              0.0
303      2018-02-12    2018-02-12     -20              0.0
301      2018-02-12    2018-02-12      7               0.0
306      2018-02-12    2018-02-12     -2               1.1
```

I need to isolate the first payment of each of the loan. and I need to do that using the **loanId**, the **min** function and a **group by**. All the first payment should be stored in a temporary table.

note **The first payment is the payment with the earliest dueday attached to the loan.**

Then. I need to join the created temporary table with the loansRepaid table described above. I can do this by joining the two tables on the loanid and where the dueday matches the minimum dueday for the respective loanid.

I am also required to select all the variables associated with the first payment of each loan, create a new variable called **paydefault** for each loan which holds (1) if the settleday associated with the first payment is greater than 7 or it is null else its holds (0). That is if the firt payment was made 7 days after the dueday or not paid at all.

here is a query I have written but I am currently stuck and don't know where to go from here.

`with firstPay as ( select loanId, min(dueday) as dueday
 from loansRepaid 
group by loanId
)
select * from firstPay as FP
join loansRepaid  as Lp
on FP.loanId = Lp.loanId
and FP.dueDate = LP.dueDate`

I also get the error- Duplicate column names in the result are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify all column references and you will minimize such problems.

```
with firstPay as (
       select lr.loanId, min(lr.dueday) as dueday
       from loansRepaid lr
       group by lr.loanId
      )
select lp.*
from firstPay fp join
     loansRepaid lr
     on fp.loanId = lr.loanId and
        fp.dueDate = lr.dueDate;
```

In this case, the solution is that you only need the rows from `lp` in the outer query.  The columns from `fp` are just duplicating those.

You may find that performance is better with a correlated subquery:

```
select lr.*
from loansrepaid lr
where lr.dueday = (select min(lr2.dueday)
                   from loansrepaid lr2
                   where lr2.loanid = lr.loanid
                  );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `loansrepaid(loanid, dueday)`.

Comment: just for clarification. in the temporary table you used the alias lr for the loanrepaid table, and used the alias lp for the loans repaid table in subquery?

Comment: @wyn . . . The alias doesn't matter.  `lr` makes more sense for `loansrepaid`.

Answer (score 0):

use alias for dueday ,loanId as both columns  exist in both table
or just use tbale prefix before column name like table.column

```
with firstPay as 
( select loanId, min(dueday) as dueday
 from loansRepaid 
 group by loanId
 )
select FP.dueday as fpdueday,FP.loanId as loinidfp from firstPay as FP
join loansRepaid  as Lp
on FP.loanId = Lp.loanId
and FP.dueDate = LP.dueDate
```

in your version is 8.0 then row_number()

```
select a.* from 

(select l.*,row_number()over(partition by loanId order by dueday) rn
from  loansRepaid l
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a 
where dueday in (select min(dueday) from tablename b where a.loanid=b.loanid)
```